# Can't put my Flareon into a gym

Tags: pokemon-go

I've used my flareon in the gym a lot, it's been about two weeks of me trying to put it in the gym but when there are free slots open it won't show some of my pokemon, mainly my higher level ones. All alive and with full hp

Comment: Does you Flareon have any HP left?

Comment: You might need to revive him

Comment: I've seen this as well, I can only add some of my more crappy pokemon. Does the gym limit to only a certain number of a particular type maybe?

Comment: No I checked that, I have full hp on each pokemon, there are 5 of them I can't use or it doesn't give me an option, all alive and full. It's not a matter of duplicates because there where four arcanine in one gym

Answer (score 4):

Any pokemon that you want to assign to a gym needs to be alive and with full HP. Go to your bag and make sure his HP is full by using potions and/or revive if necessary.